# regular expression - partially match

Tags: python, regex

My aim is to find matches in a text where not always all matches are present.

I am trying to collect the phone number, the E-mail and the website of venues from a web site. Only some venues have all three information available but most of them only one or two of them. I tried to write a code. However, it works only if all 3 information are available. Could someone help me what is wrong?

```
grouped = re.compile('col-right[\s\S]*?' +
                     'Tel[\s\S]*?([0-9]{0,4}-?[0-9]{3,7}-?[0-9]{0,4}-?[0-9]{0,4})' +
                     '[\s\S]*?href="http://([\w\W]*?)"' +
                     '[\s\S]*?href="mailto:([\s\S]*?)">[\s\S]*?</div>')
for match in re.finditer(grouped, text):
    print (match.group(1))
    print (match.group(2))
    print (match.group(3))
```

Also the digits in the phone numbers are divided with "-" but sometimes there is a space between the "-" and the next set of digits. How can I include that in the code that this space is only occasionally present?

Comment: Can you provide some sample data for what you are trying to match?  A few lines with all information and a few that are missing some of this information would be helpful.

Comment: <h2>Contact</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="col-right">
<span class="txt"><span class="txt">Tel: <span class="btxt">1-352- 2702</span>, <span class="btxt">1-324-5200</span></span><br /><span class="txt">Fax: <span class="btxt">1-342- 6765</span></span></span>
<br>
             <span class="txt">Web:</span>
<a class="bodlink" href="http://www.alma.hu” target="_blank">www.alma.hu</a>
<br>
     <span class="txt">E-mail:</span>
     <a class="bodlink"  href="mailto:info@alma.hu">info@alma.hu</a>

Comment: Please edit the question to include that sample data.

Comment: You have another problem and that is _positional_. Its not really enough to assume position because if it isn't `(this1)?.*?(this2)?.*?(this3)?` won't work. That can be fixed if you use a lookahead and have enough other cue's as to the end of record and such.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is good, but it needs a little work.

First of all, you need the phone number. Write a regex for it, and add it to a group: `(regex)*` the group is marked with ``` (``) ``` and `*` means that it has to be present 0 or more times.

Write the next regex, add it to another group `(emailRegex)*` and the third group `(website)*`.

Instead of `*` you could also use the `?`, once or none at all (as I can see, you used `?`.

Now, putting all together, simply mix them with any character in between them

```
(group1)?.*(emailRegex)?.*(website)*
```

grup1 matches phone number, followed by any character, email, followed by any character, website. And if one of them is missing, there is no problem at all.

Email regex example: (probably not the most complete one)

```
([a-zA-Z_]+[a-zA-Z_.-0-9]*@[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-z]+])?
```

This works like this: the email should start with a letter or an underscore **_** and it should be followed by lower/upper case, numbers, underscore or a dot ( **.**) followed by **@** and letters followed by a dot (notice that I used `\.` to escape the special `any character` notation and in the end you add a mix of at least a letter.

works for **email@mail.com**.

The fact that I put the entire regex in brackets means it is a group and it should appear once or none at all (hence the `?`). Between groups, you add `.*` meaning that in between the phone number/email/address can be any characters.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I am a very beginner and not familiar with regex so I do not entirely understand what you mean but I will dig into regex and see how it goes. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: No problem. The point is that you don't use `*?` because that means no matter what char gets there, it shall appear once or none at all. You need to make a group appear once or non at all.

Comment: if my answer helped you, please upvote and mark it as answer by clicking the gray tick under the score.

Comment: @MecznerAndrás, check the updated answer, got an example for you as well.

Comment: Thanks again. I thought I did what you meant but now I have no results at all. Is this really what you meant?:      grouped= re.compile('col-right.*([0-9]{0,4}-?[0-9]{3,7}-?[0-9]{0,4}-?[0-9]{0,4})?.*(www\.[a-zA-Z_]+[a-zA-Z_.-0-9]\.[a-z]+)?.*([a-zA-Z_]+[a-zA-Z_.-0-9]*@[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-z]+])?.*</div>')
    for match in re.finditer(grouped,text):
         print (match.group(1))
         print (match.group(2))
         print (match.group(3))

Comment: Actually, @sln has a point. It depends what group is first or not so it would matter what is first, you only need to check the order.

Comment: Thanks, the order is always the same: first phone, then web, then E-mail